# DataReader Working Not Clear

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

```
 protected void btnFetch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from emptable";
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    gv1.DataSource = dr;
    gv1.DataBind();

    dr.NextResult();

    **while (dr.Read())**//It is returning the value as false!
    {
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.CommandText = "select * from table1";
        Response.Write(dr[0]);
        Response.Write(dr[1]);
    }
    con.Close();
 }
```

I am confused as to why, the data reader picks up one "select statement", reads it and binds it to a Gridview but when it comes down to using the next set of "select statement", the data reader doesn't do anything. `dr.Read()` becomes `false`.

Kindly explain to me why does this happen?

Comment: What does NextResult return?

Comment: [`SqlDataReader.NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) returns `boolean` value btw

Comment: You should be using "using" on your connection and command, that way you don't have to dispose/them on your own and they will get disposed if a exception happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
 protected void btnFetch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from emptable;select * from table1";
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    gv1.DataSource = dr;
    gv1.DataBind();

    dr.NextResult();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Response.Write(dr[0]);
        Response.Write(dr[1]);
    }
    con.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code is so simple and works like a charm. Problem solved!

Comment: One extra tip use using with your connection, command and reader. That way you will get rid of memory leaks

Answer (score 2):

The data reader is forward only. that means that you can only read all rows once.

Hence when you have bound the GridView it will move through the data reader until `Read()` returns false (to be able to fill all rows).

So when you try to invoke your loop the `reader` is already in the end of the recordset.

This is explained in detail in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sh674a6a.aspx).

Update:

The `NextResult()` method is used to select the next result if you added multiple SELECT statements to the `Command.CommandText` as @Petoj showed. Hence it has no effect whatsoever in your code.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know why the "dr.read()",in the loop condition turns out to be false.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `NextResult`, `dr.NextResult();` advances the reader to the next batch:

```
using (var myCon = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConStr))
using (var selectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from emptable", myCon))
{
    myCon.Open();
    using (var dr = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read()) 
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

So if you select two tables you can use [`NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) to get the next, e.g.:

```
"select * from emptable; select * from otherTable"
```

Normally you don't need to use this method since `ExecuteReader` already returns the first batch.

Note that i'm using the [`using`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed at the end of it even in case of an exception. You should use it whenever possible. That is for every object implementing `IDisposable`(you'll get a compiler error if you try to use `using` when it's impossible).

`SqlConnection.Dispose` also closes the connection, hence you don't need to do it manually (this applies to all connection types).

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> As a rule, **when you use an `IDisposable` object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement**. The using statement **calls the
>   Dispose method** on the object in the correct way. Within the using block, the object is
>   **read-only** and cannot be modified or reassigned. The using statement
>   ensures that Dispose is called **even if an exception occurs** while you
>   are calling methods on the object.

Comment: Tim, can you plz give me a reference article on the web to using the "using" in your code. I have never used it. If possible, kindly explain it a little bit.

Comment: @kustomClass: Edited my answer (link inside).

Answer (score 0):

`dr.NextResult();` works if you have multiple select statement in your query [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx).
You have only one select statement in your table as

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from emptable";
```

So If you have to use multiple select statement then in commandtext you should have multiple select statement as follow

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from emptable;select * from table1";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write a stored procedure in sql server

CREATE PROCEDURE selectFromTwoTables
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT * FROM emptable

SELECT * FROM table1

IF(@@error = 0) -- if any error occured transaction will rollback. otherwise commit
COMMIT TRANSACTION
ELSE
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END

in c# 
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectFromTwoTables", conn);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;